# What is a method for finding if two element inside a struc array is repeated?

Tags: c

I have a `struct` of people which has ID and Names of a large quantity over 100k and I wish to see if the exact ID and Name pair shows up again, how would I got about doing this without hashmaps?

The struct looks something like this:

```
struct person_struct {
    int id;
    char name[];

    // some other fields (probably)
};
```

The number of such structures that is have is large enough that `O(n^2)` solution (two nested `for` loops) is unacceptable. Is there a more efficient method to do this?

Comment: Nested `for` loops is O(n**2) time. Sort the array, which is approx O(n*log2(n)). If the `struct` is largish, then you could create an array of _pointers_ to the `struct` and sort that. Then, you can compare the array element by element in O(n) time

Comment: If you don't mind using probabilistic methods you could use a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) that allows you to find all elements that are **probably** duplicates with a single pass `O(n)` in time, `O(1)` in space. (you can fine-tune the rate of false positives you're comfortable with by increasing the number of bits used for the filter and using a good hashing function). If you want to know for sure if they're actually duplicates you'd have to keep track of the duplicates and do a second pass to cross-check the result.

Comment: @CraigEstey is creating a comparator and then qsorting it efficient ? The original file is completely random in order. If not how would i go about sorting the struc, I already have a array that is People ** peoples filled.

Comment: Why do you think to need two `for` loops? Use just one, looking for the ID. If it matches, check the name. If it matches also, you have found it, else keep looping. This is O(n).

Comment: @thebusybee For unsorted arrays, for the simple algorithm, we need _two_ loops regardless of the complexity of the compare. The loops are to compare every element against every other element. Of course, _each_ compare is two step: ID then Name [if ID matches] but that doesn't influence which element is compared against which other element.

Comment: @thebusybee Sorry if i'm misunderstanding but doesn't this only check if one of the IDs matches up with every other ID not all IDs against each other? If this is not the case can you give an example code snipet?

Comment: Creating a comparator and doing `qsort` _is_ efficient (i.e.) what I said: O(n*log2(n)). If you have (e.g.) `People *people_list;` And, then already have `People **indirect_list;` that points within `people_list`, you already have the pointer array. If `Names` is large (e.g. `char Names[100];`), then sorting the indirect list might be faster because swapping 8 bytes is faster than swapping 104 bytes. But, you can sort _either_ list. Sorting original _might_ be better if the overhead of creating the indirect list exceeds the sort time of the first.

Comment: You could create a binary tree using ids   as key of the node and the location of the name in the file as data. When you encounter an identical id go to read the name in the file and compare it. if it is different there is probably a problem otherwise you increment a counter in the node. I believe this is fast if there isn't the same id in the whole file.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I thought you would like to see, if some given ID/name pair is already in the array. Well, if you look for _any_ non-unique multiples, do like the others suggest.